# Disabling autocompletion of `\(\)` in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion, parentheses

I am using TeXstudio 2.12.6 QT 5.9.1, and have the `Auto Complete Parentheses` in Special options turned on.
In general, it automatically 'closes' the brackets / braces for the following combinations:

```
(, [, {, \(, \[, \{
```

**QN:** Is there a way to disable the autocompletion of just *one* of the combination?

In particular, I do not like the `\(` completion, because more often than not, this combination of keypresses is a mistake, rather than on purpose.

As a result, I then have to press backspace twice, and press delete twice to remove the entire `\(\)`, which is a pain.

Answer (score 2):

The only way around is to disable *Auto Complete Parentheses* option and get back the functionality only for desired brackets via macros.

For example, for regular parenthesis `()` you need to create such macro

```
(%|)
```

here `%|` means that the cursor will be placed there after macros has been run. In order to trigger it, you need to specify the pattern, in this case `\(`
[image]

**Note!** Trigger is a regex pattern, but `(` is a special character , so you need to escape that `\(`.

For instance, the auto completion of `\[\]` would require `\\\[` as a trigger, since we firstly escape the backslash and then escape the bracket.